# How to maintain certain rows with conditions on a sample with pandas dataframe functions

Tags: python, pandas, point-clouds

I have a dataframe like this:

```
  SeqNumber X  Y  Z
0  12        4  5  5
1  12        7  5  -8
2  13        10 2  1
3  16        4  8  7 
...
```

I would like to identify the corresponding SeqNumbers to a positive Z value in a sample between a X_min, X_max and Y_min, Y_max and then just keep those SeqNumbers on the whole dataframe. How can I do that by using .loc?

If I define x_min = 3, x_max = 8, y_min = 4 and y_max = 6. Only the first 2 lines would be selected. Then of those lines, just the first one has a positive Z. So to end my problem I would like to maintain all the rows with the SeqNumber of the first line (the one who was selected before). With that the code would result with a dataframe with the first 2 lines of the original

Comment: I realize I don't understand what is the expected output! Please can you check if my answer solves your problem?

Comment: I have a dataframe with millions of rows. What a need to do is to select certain SeqNumbers from a square region that gives me a positive Z value in that region, and then want to remove all the rows that don't have that SeqNumbers from the original dataframe. Can u understand it better now?

Comment: I think what I want is the second part of ur answer. In that case if I defined a region with x_min, x_max, y_min, and y_max that integrates the point 4 5 5, I want it to maintain all rows with a SeqNumber of 12 in the original dataframe. Is that what it is doing?

Comment: OK, I almost get it. I also think you need the second part but what is the expected outcome for your sample?

Comment: I dont want any outcome of my sample. I just want to filter my whole dataframe by applying a condition only to a certain region

Comment: How can I check if my solution is valid if you expect nothing?

Comment: @LuisFerreira It would help if you could edit your question by specifying which of the four examples rows that you've shown you want to keep, and which rows you want to remove, and explain why which rows was removed. Your problem is simple and there is a simple solution, but the phrasing of your problem is slightly ambiguous and might be interpreted differently than you intended it; showing the result on the example helps remove that ambiguity.

Comment: @Stef Sorry for that. I just edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compute x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max with `agg` and search rows that match your conditions:

```
x_min = 3
x_max = 8
y_min = 4
y_max = 6

idx = df.loc[df['Z'].gt(0) & df['X'].between(x_min, y_max)
                            & df['Y'].between(y_min, y_max),
             'SeqNumber'].values

out = df.loc[df['SeqNumber'].isin(idx)]
```

Output:

```
>>> idx
array([12])

>>> out
   SeqNumber  X  Y  Z
0         12  4  5  5
1         12  7  5 -8
```

Comment: could u just explain me what this part does                                                              
      [   df1['Z'].ge(0) & df1['Z'].between(df1['x_min'], df1['y_max']) & df1['Z'].between(df1['y_min'], df1['y_max'])   ]

Comment: IIUC, the code above checks conditions Z >= 0 and x_min <= Z <= x_max and y_min <= Z <= y_max.

Comment: hmm ok, its not what I want but I think I can modify this. thank u very much

Comment: The community can help you more but we need input and output data especially when the problem is not trivial. (and ty for your support!)

Comment: @Corralien Although the question might be interpreted differently, the first interpretation that came to me when I read it was "I have four parameters called (y_min, y_max, x_min, x_max), and I want to select rows that satisfy (x_min <= X <= x_max and y_min <= Y <= y_max and 0 < Z)". Instead, your answer assumes that x_min is not a parameter, but the minimum of the column, and calculates it.

Comment: @Stef. I don't know if the post was edited before or after your comment but the last paragraph was added after my answer. Now, there is no ambiguity anymore. I will update my answer today.

Comment: @LuisFerreira. I updated my answer. It should be right now.

Comment: Note that `df['Z'].ge(0)` accepts nonnegative values for Z. Technically the question asked for positive values for Z. In that case, `.gt` would be more suited than `.ge`. Documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ge.html